# Gimp: web preview is blurry

Tags: gimp, resolution, illustration, scanning

I'm scanning black and white drawings onto my computer and cleaning them up with GIMP so they are all crisp and clean but (after resizing them for the web -roughly 1000 pixels and 75dpi) they appear blurring in previews until you click into them...does anyone know why this is?

I'm frustrated because it looks like a hack job until you actually click in...
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Don't know what you mean by "blurring in previews until you click into them". How are you previewing the image?  When rescaling the image are you using the Sinc(Lanzos3) interpolation method? Set the zoom level at 100% to preview an image how it will look in a browser.

Comment: If the preview is on a web site, the web site may be using recompressed images to save bandwidth. Download the preview image and compare to your original.